# How to display form or dialog when user clicks in a Google Spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Spreadsheet, where each cell contains some plain text information. Now I need to pop-up a Google Form or UI Service dialog where user can enter that information field-by-field. Are there any way to get some event when user clicks/taps on a spreadsheet's cell? Spent a lot of time reading Google Apps Script documentation but found nothing helpful. Are there any way to get such event or maybe some workaround exists?

UPD: Now users enter data into cells as plain text. One can say that in-place text editor of a cell is their interface to editing this cell. What I'm trying to do is to change cell editing interface. I want users to be able to edit cell only through my form. When user fills form for a cell for the first time, the answer is saved to a separate sheet and the cell which user is trying to edit is populated with concatenation of user's answers. When user clicks on a cell that was previously populated, again my form appears pre-populated with prevous answers.

Comment: You can assign a function to a button or menu action which can prompt for data entry and hen populate cells with input data. 

Do you want this action on a single or multiple cells? The question isn't clear.

Comment: I need f form to pop up for a single active cell. As of now, it seems your suggestion about a menu item or a button is the only way.

Comment: can you rethink the problem and have a form capture data from your users rather than having a spreadsheet as the interface?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google Apps Script triggers are restricted to the ones listed in the [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) documentation page.  There is not, currently, a trigger that will fire when a new cell becomes active -- the closest functionality is the onEdit trigger, which fires when any cell in the spreadsheet is changed.

A common use case is for user interactions with a Form or dialog to result in changes in a backend Spreadsheet.  If I understood you correctly, it sounds like you are trying to do the reverse.  You might want to rethink your approach here to make sure you really need a 'newActive' trigger functionality, or if you can make do with the existing triggers.

Comment: Ryan, please see update in question's description. My aim is to make form the only interface to editing cell contents. The "newActive" trigger functionality is not quite what I need, but rather "onTryEdit" or "onDoubleClick" trigger functionality.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I believe you can roughly approximate the behavior you want by using onEdit(event), and checking if the event fired was tied to your target cell.  If it was, call a function to clear the data the user entered, summon your form page, and replace the cell contents.

Comment: There is a caveat, however -- currently in the new version of Sheets [the ability to identify the edited cell is bugged](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3496), and has not been repaired yet.  The old version of Sheets does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but it seems that Google has added this functionality with `onSelectionChange`.

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee):

> The `onSelectionChange(e)` trigger runs automatically when a user changes the selection in a spreadsheet.